# How to get previous value of a field in Validaton Rule

Tags: custom-object

I have a Master - Detail Relationship from Crop to Agri Form. 
Agri Form has it's own size(in yards). A Form may have many Crops in this Year. Each Crop also has it's own size.

Agri Form has 'Form In Use' Roll-up Summary Field which is the sum of All Corp's Size

[image]

I want to inforce a validation rule On Crop Object saying "The new size of this Crop should not exceed the Empty Form size".
here is the Validation Rule on Crop Object

```
Size__c > (Agri_Form__r.size__c - Agri_Form__r.Form_In_Use__c )
```

But this does not work as I expected.
`Agri_Form__r.Form_In_Use__c` already included the Previous size of current Crop.

```
Size__c > (Agri_Form__r.size__c - Agri_Form__r.Form_In_Use__c - [Previous value of Size__c])
```

Is there a way to get the Previous value of Size__c from the Crop Object ?
Or is there any other way to implement this scenario?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [PriorValue](https://help.salesforce.com/htviewhelpdoc?id=customize_functions_i_z.htm&siteLang=en_US#PRIORVALUE) function, like

```
Size__c > (Agri_Form__r.size__c - Agri_Form__r.Form_In_Use__c - PRIORVALUE(Size__c))
```

Answer (score 0):

The formula builder will let you bring in values from the master record in this case, but validation rules don't have a way to get at previous values of other records.  In other words, this should only be done if the value you're bringing in won't change as a result of your update (which is not the case here).

From "Best Practices" section [here](https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=fields_about_roll_up_summary_fields.htm&language=en):

> Avoid referencing a roll-up summary field from a child record. The roll-up summary field will have the previous value because the parent record has not been updated. If you reference a roll-up summary field from a parent record, the roll-up summary field will always have the new value because that rule runs after the parent value has been updated.

I think a trigger is the only way to approach this situation.

Comment: They are looking for the previous value on the Crop object that is being saved, not the master Acre object.  Both have a field named Size__c.